# why this code is giving this message during compilation "could not convert 'trip' from 'std::vector' to 'std::vector >"?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, search

> You are given an array/list ARR consisting of N integers. Your task is to find all the distinct triplets present in the array which adds up to a given number K.
>
> An array is said to have a triplet `{ARR[i], ARR[j], ARR[k]}` with `sum = 'K'` if there exists three indices `i`, `j` and `k` such that `i!=j`, `j!=k` and `i!=j` and `ARR[i] + ARR[j] + ARR[k] = 'K'`.

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> findTriplets(vector<int>arr, int n, int K) {
    vector<int>trip;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            for(int k=j+1;k<n;k++){
                if(arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]==K){
                    trip.push_back(arr[i]);
                    trip.push_back(arr[j]);
                    trip.push_back(arr[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return trip;
}
```

Comment: That's not the complete error message. Vectors also know their size. `n` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: trip  is `vector<int>` but your function is declared to return `vector<vector<int>>` which are 2 different things.

Comment: `trip.push_back({arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]});`

Comment: @sweenish   Compilation Failed
In file included from runner.cpp:7:0:
solution.h: In function 'std::vector > findTriplets(std::vector, int, int)':
solution.h:15:16: error: could not convert 'trip' from 'std::vector' to 'std::vector >'
         return trip;   this is what I receive during compilation.

Comment: @molbdnilo this is not working.

Comment: @drescherjm How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you really want to return a `vector<vector<int>>`? Or can you just fix the return value.

Comment: By the naming I think you wanted to make `vector<vector<int>> trip;` and use the line from @molbdnilo `trip.push_back({arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]});` instead of your 3 push_back()

Comment: @drescherjm vector<vector<int>> this function is already given I have to complete this function.How I can fix it?

Comment: Edit the error message **into the question**, please.

Comment: The change I mentioned compiled successfully here: [https://ideone.com/UE8RqV](https://ideone.com/UE8RqV)

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that the return type of your function `findTriplets` is a **2D vector** while what you're actually returning(`trip`) is a **1D vector**.

To **solve** this, you just have to match the type of what you're actually returning with the return type of the function as shown below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//also note that we don't have to pass the size of the vector as second argument because we can use size() member function of vector
vector<vector<int>> findTriplets(vector<int>arr, int K) {
        
    vector<vector<int>> tempVec;
    vector<int> trip;
    int n = arr.size();//find n using arr.size()

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            for(int k=j+1;k<n;k++){
                if(arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]==K){
                    trip.push_back(arr.at(i));
                    trip.push_back(arr.at(j));
                    trip.push_back(arr.at(k));
                        
                    //add trip to tempVec
                    tempVec.push_back(trip);
                        
                    //clear trip 
                    trip.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return tempVec;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {12, 3, 4, 1, 6, 9,8,7};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result = findTriplets(vec, 24);
    std::cout << "triplets are:" << std::endl;
    for(const std::vector<int> &vec: result)
    {
        for(const int &element: vec)
        {
            std::cout << element << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
triplets are:
12 3 9 
12 4 8 
9 8 7
```

Which can be verified [here](https://onlinegdb.com/loSmlFBCl).

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Make what you return match what you say you will return. It's fairly straightforward in that regard.

Comment: @HimanshuMishra I have added how to solve your problem at the end of my answer. Check it out. Basically you need to match the return type of the function with the type of the value you're actually returning. The output of the solution can also be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/loSmlFBCl). That is, the solution to your problem is added at the end of my (edited)answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<vector<int>> findTriplets(vector<int>arr, int n, int K) {
    // Write your code here.
    vector< vector<int>> ans;
    vector<int> temp;
    for(int i =0; i<n-2; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<n-1; j++){
            for(int k= j+1; k<n; k++){
                if(arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]==K){
                    temp.push_back(arr[i]);
                    temp.push_back(arr[j]);
                    temp.push_back(arr[k]);
                    ans.push_back(temp); 
                    return ans;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

its helps you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).